# Scope resolution error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I am working on shared memory in windows.

### I am also memorybarrier in my code.On compiling the code in visual studio 2012 using command prompt i am getting error.

```
#include "shmem_kk.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#else
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#endif
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace kk_win;

namespace IPC
{

    void
        Shm::get_lock(packet *map) {
            map[COUNT + 1].value = 1;               // flag[0] = 1
#ifdef _WIN32
            MemoryBarrier();            // compiler barriers
#else
            __sync_synchronize();
#endif
            map[COUNT + 3].value = 1;               // turn = 1
#ifdef _WIN32
            MemoryBarrier();            // compiler barriers
#else
            __sync_synchronize();
#endif
            while ((map[COUNT + 2].value == 1) && (map[COUNT + 3].value == 1)) {}
        }

    void
        Shm::release_lock(packet *map) {
            map[COUNT + 1].value = 0;
#ifdef _WIN32
            MemoryBarrier();            // compiler barriers
#else
            __sync_synchronize();
#endif
        }
```

---

On visual studio i am getting error

```
shmem_kk.cc(30) : error C2668: '__faststorefence' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(302): could be 'void __faststorefence(voi
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2824): or       'void kk_win::__faststorefence(void)
        while trying to match the argument list '(void)'
shmem_kk.cc(36) : error C2668: '__faststorefence' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(302): could be 'void __faststorefence(voi
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2824): or       'void kk_win::__faststorefence(void)
        while trying to match the argument list '(void)'
shmem_kk.cc(47) : error C2668: '__faststorefence' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(302): could be 'void __faststorefence(voi
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(2824): or       'void kk_win::__faststorefence(void)
        while trying to match the argument list '(void)'
```

---

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Get rid of the using namespace.

Comment: @RichardCritten i was doing some typo error.After your comment i tried and it worked .thanks.